# terraform output map value from lists of maps

Tags: terraform

I want to get a specific map element from a lists of maps in Terraform's output.

For example, how would I access `account` in `properties.json` for each map item
and print a list as output conditionally for `type` also.

I tried `for` loops and `splat` expressions as below but it does not return exact value.

It seems that the props below is also a list.

```
    output "resources_by_name" {
      description = "Resource name of all machine type resources from a vRA deployment"
      value = [
        for props in deployment.deploy[*].resources.*.properties_json:
        jsondecode(props).account
        if jsondecode(props).type == "vsphere"        
        ]
    }
```

I am not sure how to use nested for loops or access map items within the lists.

**properties.json**

```
    [
      [
        {
          "id" = "b5336bf7-07fb-4026-aa3d-479bd974ca45"
          "name" = "test1"
          "properties_json" = "{"account":"test0","constraints":"anothertest4"}"
          "type" = "vsphere"
        },
        {
          "id" = "67a3380b-8008-4f9c-9c13-2a1a935d5820"
          "name" = "test2"
          "properties_json" = "{"account":"test1","constraints":"anothertest3"}"
          "type" = "gcp"
        },
      ],
      [
        {
          "id" = "eeddd127-cba2-4b34-a2d7-e56dda5d2974"
          "name" = "test3"
          "properties_json" = "{"account":"test2","constraints":"anothertest2"}"
          "type" = "aws"
        },
        {
          "id" = "81de1857-c0c9-4c9e-8fbd-d8a1da64fa3c"
          "name" = "test4"
          "properties_json" = "{"account":"test3","constraints":"anothertest1"}"
          "type" = "az"
        },
      ],
    ]
```

Comment: Your `properties.json` is not a valid json. Can you double check this or provide valid example?

Comment: Updated now. This should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is **working** example. I had to fill out the blanks missing from your question, thus you may need to modify it to suit your needs:

```
locals {
  properties =     [
      [
        {
          "id" = "b5336bf7-07fb-4026-aa3d-479bd974ca45"
          "name" = "test1"
          "properties_json" = "{\"account\":\"test0\",\"constraints\":\"anothertest4\"}"
          "type" = "vsphere"
        },
        {
          "id" = "67a3380b-8008-4f9c-9c13-2a1a935d5820"
          "name" = "test2"
          "properties_json" = "{\"account\":\"test1\",\"constraints\":\"anothertest3\"}"
          "type" = "gcp"
        },
      ],
      [
        {
          "id" = "eeddd127-cba2-4b34-a2d7-e56dda5d2974"
          "name" = "test3"
          "properties_json" = "{\"account\":\"test2\",\"constraints\":\"anothertest2\"}"
          "type" = "aws"
        },
        {
          "id" = "81de1857-c0c9-4c9e-8fbd-d8a1da64fa3c"
          "name" = "test4"
          "properties_json" = "{\"account\":\"test3\",\"constraints\":\"anothertest1\"}"
          "type" = "az"
        },
      ],
    ]
}

output "resources_by_name" {
  value = [for props in flatten(local.properties):
           jsondecode(props.properties_json).account 
             if props.type == "vsphere"   
          ]
}
```

Outcome:

```
resources_by_name = [
  "test0",
]
```